# How to add a GoogleMap Search Box to my customized map?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, searchbar

I'm developing my own map with google API and IGN API (french map) and I'd like to add a Google Map Search Box but can't find a way to succeed even after reading carefully the Google Map API.

This is what I have:
http://www.tiphainebuccino.com/site/Map/LaCarteAuxTresors_2.html

This is what I want to add (without losing my actual settings):
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox?hl=fr

I don't understand how to mix the two html codes. Someone could help me?
I work in html+javascript.

The relevant (non-working) code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>La Tarte Aux Crésors "Beta"</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    "use strict";

    var ignKey = "ljozkgwvms60dtumhx67z6u3"

    function makeIGNMapType(layer, name, maxZoom) {
        return new google.maps.ImageMapType({
            getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
                return "http://gpp3-wxs.ign.fr/" + ignKey + "/geoportail/wmts?LAYER=" +
                    layer +
                    "&EXCEPTIONS=text/xml&FORMAT=image/jpeg&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0" +
                    "&REQUEST=GetTile&STYLE=normal&TILEMATRIXSET=PM&TILEMATRIX=" +
                    zoom + "&TILEROW=" + coord.y + "&TILECOL=" + coord.x;
            },
            tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256,256),
            name: name,
            maxZoom: maxZoom
        });
    }

    function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, {
            mapTypeId: 'IGN',
            scaleControl: true,
            streetViewControl: true,
            panControl: true,
            mapTypeControl:true,
            overviewMapControl: true,
            overviewMapControlOptions: {
opened: true,
position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER 
},


            mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [
                    'IGN', 'IGNScanExpress',
                    google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP],
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
            },
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(47, 3),
            zoom: 6,
            draggableCursor: "crosshair"
        });

        map.mapTypes.set('IGN', makeIGNMapType("GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.MAPS", "IGN", 18));
        map.mapTypes.set('IGNScanExpress', makeIGNMapType("GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.MAPS.SCAN-EXPRESS.CLASSIQUE", "IGN Scan Express", 16));


  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));

  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }

    // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
  // current map's viewport.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });
}

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<style>
html, body, #map_canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I get this error on [your map](http://www.tiphainebuccino.com/site/Map/LaCarteAuxTresors_2.html):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SearchBox' of undefined
```

You need to [include the places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) when you load the API.

Change:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

You also don't have an element with id="pac-input" on your page. Add this to your HTML markup:

```
<input id="pac-input"></input>
```

[Working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_PlacesAPI_LaCarteAuxTresors_2.html)

code snippet (with moon tiles as the originals are no longer available):

```js
var ignKey = "ljozkgwvms60dtumhx67z6u3"
var markers = [];

function makeIGNMapType(layer, name, maxZoom) {
  return new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
      var normalizedCoord = getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom);
      if (!normalizedCoord) {
        return null;
      }
      var bound = Math.pow(2, zoom);
      return 'http://mw1.google.com/mw-planetary/lunar/lunarmaps_v1/clem_bw' +
        '/' + zoom + '/' + normalizedCoord.x + '/' +
        (bound - normalizedCoord.y - 1) + '.jpg';
    },
    name: 'Moon',
  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
  maxZoom: 9,
  minZoom: 0
  });
}

function initialize() {
  var map_canvas = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

  var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, {
    mapTypeId: 'IGN',
    scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: true,
    panControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    overviewMapControl: true,
    overviewMapControlOptions: {
      opened: true,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
    },


    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [
        'IGN', 'IGNScanExpress',
        google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      ],
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
    },
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47, 3),
    zoom: 6,
    draggableCursor: "crosshair"
  });

  map.mapTypes.set('IGN', makeIGNMapType("GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.MAPS", "IGN", 18));
  map.mapTypes.set('IGNScanExpress', makeIGNMapType("GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.MAPS.SCAN-EXPRESS.CLASSIQUE", "IGN Scan Express", 16));


  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */ (
    document.getElementById('pac-input'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (input));

  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }

    // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var place = null;
    var viewport = null;
    for (var i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });
      viewport = place.geometry.viewport;
      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
  });

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
  // current map's viewport.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });
}


// Normalizes the coords that tiles repeat across the x axis (horizontally)
// like the standard Google map tiles.
function getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom) {
  var y = coord.y;
  var x = coord.x;

  // tile range in one direction range is dependent on zoom level
  // 0 = 1 tile, 1 = 2 tiles, 2 = 4 tiles, 3 = 8 tiles, etc
  var tileRange = 1 << zoom;

  // don't repeat across y-axis (vertically)
  if (y < 0 || y >= tileRange) {
    return null;
  }

  // repeat across x-axis
  if (x < 0 || x >= tileRange) {
    x = (x % tileRange + tileRange) % tileRange;
  }

  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
}






google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<input id="pac-input" />
```