# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SearchBox' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm running a code for google map which can display public schools or private schools with different markers each, when I run the code, it has an error on this line:

```
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
```

The error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SearchBox' of undefined

What is the problem with my code?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Places Search Box</title>
<style>
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#description {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#infowindow-content .title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#infowindow-content {
  display: none;
}

#map #infowindow-content {
  display: inline;
}

.pac-card {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#pac-container {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.pac-controls {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

.pac-controls label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#title {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

#target {
  width: 345px;
}
</style>
</head>
  <body>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places.js"></script>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -33.8688,
      lng: 151.2195
    },
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      if (!place.geometry) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }

      var icons = {
        'Public school': {
          icon: 'http://i68.tinypic.com/xcnnz4.png'
        },
        'Private school': {
          icon: 'http://i67.tinypic.com/2utkz8k.png'
        }
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}

initAutocomplete();
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error means that `google.maps.places` is `undefined`. Whether that's correct or not, I can't say, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a GoogleMap Search Box to my customized map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21412111/how-to-add-a-googlemap-search-box-to-my-customized-map)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to include the [places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) correctly ("places.js" should be just "places"):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBawDPz1seR1vu-Fw62CDRjmMU6B_oDOZ4&libraries=places.js"></script>
```

should be:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBawDPz1seR1vu-Fw62CDRjmMU6B_oDOZ4&libraries=places"></script>
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Lv4z5a6u/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#description {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#infowindow-content .title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#infowindow-content {
  display: none;
}

#map #infowindow-content {
  display: inline;
}

.pac-card {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#pac-container {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.pac-controls {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

.pac-controls label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#title {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

#target {
  width: 345px;
}
```

```html
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places"></script>    
<script>
  function initAutocomplete() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {
        lat: -33.8688,
        lng: 151.2195
      },
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
      searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    var markers = [];
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
      var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

      if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
      }

      // Clear out the old markers.
      markers.forEach(function(marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
      });
      markers = [];

      // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      places.forEach(function(place) {
        if (!place.geometry) {
          console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
          return;
        }

        // Create a marker for each place.
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          title: place.name,
          position: place.geometry.location
        }));

        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          // Only geocodes have viewport.
          bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
      });
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
  }

  initAutocomplete();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the callback in the api url so it runs after the places library is loaded. Remove the call to initAutocomplete at the end of your javascript.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBawDPz1seR1vu-Fw62CDRjmMU6B_oDOZ4&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```